# Pyomo scip solver Error FileNotFoundError

Tags: ubuntu, pyomo, scip

I am trying to use [scip](https://scipopt.org/index.php#download) solver in [pyomo](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) on ubuntu 20.04 but get a strange error message when invoking the solver:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpxsrkdky5.pyomo.sol'

`pyomo` was installed via `pip` and `scip` was installed via the installer script on their  [download page](https://scipopt.org/index.php#download). I was unable to install the `.deb` file because of dependency issues -- being on Ubuntu 20.04 instead of 18.04. The installer script installed `scip` in a folder in my home directory, but I do provide the path to the solver in my python script.

Minimal Working Example:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

# basic setup
Agents = list(range(10))
Values = [1, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4, 1]
Weight = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 2, 3, 1]

# create pyo model and set variable
Dummy = pyo.ConcreteModel()
Dummy.x = pyo.Var(Agents, bounds=(0, 1))

# set objective
Dummy.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=(sum(Dummy.x[i]*Values[i] for i in Agents)))

# add a constraint
Dummy.constraint = pyo.ConstraintList()
Dummy.constraint.add(sum(Dummy.x[i]*Weight[i] for i in Agents) <= 10)

# select solver and solve problem
opt = pyo.SolverFactory('scip', executable='/path/to/solver/SCIPOptSuite-7.0.1-Linux/bin/scip')
opt.solve(Dummy)
```

Edit:
I was not able to solve the pyomo model with scip. However, I was able to directly model and solve the problem using [PySCIPOpt](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt). The [Examples](http://scip-interfaces.github.io/PySCIPOpt/docs/html/bpp_8py_source.html) in their documentation helped quite a bit.

```
from pyscipopt import Model, quicksum

# basic setup
Agents = list(range(10))
Values = [1, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4, 1]
Weight = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 2, 3, 1]

#==================solve it straight with scip================================
Dummy = Model("dummy")
# vtype='C' means the variable is continuous
x = [Dummy.addVar(lb = 0, ub=1, name=("x" + str(i)), vtype='C') for i in Agents]

# set objective
Dummy.setObjective(quicksum(x[i]*Values[i] for i in Agents), sense="maximize")

# add a constraint
Dummy.addCons(quicksum(x[i]*Weight[i] for i in Agents) <= 10)

# solve problem
Dummy.optimize()
sol = Dummy.getBestSol()
print(sol)
```

EditEdit:
Yesterday it still worked, but trying to run it again today, it returns a trivial solution and not the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The issue arises because you are pointing `pyomo` directly to the `scip` executable, rather than the AMPL interface that `pyomo` needs. Unfortunately, the AMPL interface does not seem to be included anymore in the pre-compiled installer (I tried the *.deb approach, and it was not there).

Luckily, though, building `scipampl` from the source code is very straightforward. I followed these instructions exactly with version 7.0.3:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66736905/7382307

And then in was just a matter of

```
from pyomo import environ as po
opt = po.SolverFactory('scipampl')
```

Alternatively, for those willing to use an older version (6.0), this seems to also fix the problem, at least on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56886542/7382307

Comment: SCIP 8 seems to have the AMPL interface built in. So you just need to install it, then use `po.SolverFactory('scip', solver_io='nl')`. `solver_io='nl'` forces Pyomo to use the AMPL interface instead of SCIP's own interface (which didn't work for me).