# Installation of SCIP 7.0.2 with AMPL on Ubuntu Linux 20.04 for usage with Pyomo

Tags: pyomo, ampl, scip

I want to install the [SCIP solver](http://www.scipopt.org) in version `7.0.2` on my Ubuntu Linux 20.04 machine to use in [Pyomos](http://www.pyomo.org) SolverFactory following the instructions in [this](https://www.zverovich.net/2012/08/07/using-scip-with-ampl.html) manual.

But when I use `make` I get the following error:

```
crd@crd-laptop:~/Downloads$ cd scipoptsuite-7.0.2/
crd@crd-laptop:~/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2$ make
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/cord/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2“ wird betreten
** Creating directory "/home/cord/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/scip/lib/static".
** Creating directory "/home/cord/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/scip/lib/include".
** Creating directory "/home/cord/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/scip/lib/include/zimplinc".
** Creating directory "/home/cord/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/scip/lib/include/".

** Building SoPlex library "/home/cord/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/soplex/lib/libsoplex.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.a".
make[2]: Verzeichnis „/home/cord/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/soplex“ wird betreten
make[3]: Verzeichnis „/home/cord/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/soplex“ wird betreten
make[3]: Verzeichnis „/home/cord/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/soplex“ wird verlassen
make[3]: Verzeichnis „/home/cord/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/soplex“ wird betreten
-> compiling obj/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/soplex/clufactor_rational.o
In file included from src/soplex/clufactor_rational.cpp:18:
src/soplex/spxdefines.h:46:10: fatal error: boost/multiprecision/number.hpp: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
   46 | #include "boost/multiprecision/number.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [Makefile:503: obj/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/soplex/clufactor_rational.o] Fehler 1
make[3]: Verzeichnis „/home/cord/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/soplex“ wird verlassen
make[2]: *** [Makefile:375: makelibfile] Fehler 2
make[2]: Verzeichnis „/home/cord/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/soplex“ wird verlassen
make[1]: *** [Makefile.doit:187: /home/cord/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/soplex/lib/libsoplex.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.a] Fehler 2
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/cord/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2“ wird verlassen
make: *** [Makefile:85: scipbinary] Fehler 2
```

Using it on my Windows machine with the AMPL bindings worked perfectly but I got stuck here.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could now solve the problem on my own using your hints! The trick was to compile using the flags `BOOST=false` and `ZIMPL=false` and now it works like a charm with pyomo's `SolverFactory`.

These are the commands that worked for me (output is surpressed):

```
user@machine:~/Downloads$ $ sudo apt install g++ zlib1g-dev bison flex libgmp-dev libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev
user@machine:~/Downloads$ tar xzf scipoptsuite-7.0.2.tgz 
user@machine:~/Downloads$ cd scipoptsuite-7.0.2/
user@machine:~/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2$ make BOOST=false ZIMPL=false
user@machine:~/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2$ cd scip/interfaces/ampl/
user@machine:~/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/scip/interfaces/ampl$ ./get.ASL
user@machine:~/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/scip/interfaces/ampl$ cd solvers/
user@machine:~/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/scip/interfaces/ampl/solvers$ sh configurehere
user@machine:~/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/scip/interfaces/ampl/solvers$ make
user@machine:~/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/scip/interfaces/ampl/solvers$ cd ..
user@machine:~/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/scip/interfaces/ampl$ make 
user@machine:~/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/scip/interfaces/ampl$ cd ..
user@machine:~/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/scip/interfaces$ sudo cp ampl/bin/scipampl /usr/local/bin/
```

Within pyomo, the  [solver interface](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/working_abstractmodels/pyomo_command.html#direct-interfaces-to-solvers) can be set to the nl format if not detected automatically using `solver_io='nl'`.

Thanks @Leon for pointing me in the right direction!

***Edit***: If `libboost-all-dev` is installed via `apt install` it also works with `BOOST=true`.

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner. Maybe a bit of clarification: The issue you had with `ZIMPL` is probably a missing GMP library. `Boost` is only used within SoPlex but is not relevant if you just want to use SoPlex within SCIP.

Comment: Thanks. This leads away from the initial question, but: is the setup I chose for the compilation the fastest one to solve LP/MIPs?

Comment: I tried installing SCIP 8.0.4 following these instructions but there is no scip/interfaces/ampl/ directory after running make, any tips?

Answer (score 1):

did you try rebuilding with `make BOOST=false`?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28577369)

Comment: Hi Leon! Thanks a lot for your answer which seemed to work for building `scip` and `ampl` as described in the abovementioned manual. But now I get an error when copying the executable using `crd@crd-laptop:~/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.2/scip/interfaces/ampl$ sudo cp bin/scipampl /usr/local/bin/` which says that no executable `scipampl` can be found in the folder `bin`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Here's a gist of the inputs and outputs: https://gist.github.com/ckaldemeyer/ae94be95597939ac6284661bf66bde21

Comment: I have now tried again using `BOOST=false` in all `make` commands and updated my gist. Now I get an error: `reader_zpl.c:(.text+0x3228): undefined reference to `numb_todbl'`

Comment: Thanks for your hints :)

Comment: @JinLee This does provide an answer to the question ;)